# How to install through pip

Tags: python, pyinstaller, keylogger, pyhook

I was trying to make a keylogger but i couldn't download the Pyhook module

[image]

Comment: You are trying to install a module  that is intended for a later version of Python than 3.5. The easiest solution would be to install a more recent version.

Comment: fstrings were introduced in python 3.6. python 3.5 is therefore unable to recognise them.

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question to indicate that you are having trouble getting pip to run properly.

I think there is an issue with the pip installer for Python 3.5, so what you have installed in your system is not working properly. Be sure to look for an old-enough version of the get-pip.py bootstrap script. (Search explicitly for installing pip on your Python version, 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

Install python again and include pip while installing it from the custom install section, and then try

```
pip install pyhook=1.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't create the pip syntax correctly.

supposed to be `pip install pyhook`

Answer (score 0):

You can install `pip` on windows using

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows

and proceed with the keylogger module like this

`pip install keylogger` for the keylogger

and

`pip install pyhook` for `pyhook`

Answer (score 0):

please refer '''pypi.org/project/pyHook/'''
this could help you out .
also check with syntax
this should be like pip install pyhook

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues earlier trying to look up your issue. It looks like for a brief time, the installer for pip was broken for Python 3.5.

You need to download this script and run it with your python.

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py